# Reactive table with reactive banana and gtk2hs

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming, frp, reactive-banana

I have written a small application which tracks my progress in TV Series. The application is written in Haskell with functional reactive programming (FRP) with [reactive banana](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Reactive-banana).

The application can:

- add/remove new TV Series to the table
- change the season and episode of an series

[image: App Screenshot]

I have problems writing the code that adds a new TV series to the table and wires the new events. The CRUD example from [here](https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/reactive-banana/blob/master/reactive-banana-wx/src/CRUD.hs) didn't quite help me because I have more requirements then just selecting an element from the list.

How do I write a `reactiveTable` function like the `reactiveListDisplay` function from the [CRUD Example](https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/reactive-banana/blob/master/reactive-banana-wx/src/CRUD.hs) in a FRP way? How can events be added for the remove button and the season and episode spin buttons after the network has been compiled?

```
data Series = Series { name :: String
                     , season :: Int
                     , episode :: Int
                     }


insertIntoTable :: TableClass t => t -> SeriesChangeHandler -> SeriesRemoveHandler -> Series -> IO ()
insertIntoTable table changeHandler removeHandler (Series name s e) = do
   (rows, cols) <- tableGetSize table
   tableResize table (rows+1) cols

   nameLabel     <- labelNew $ Just name 
   adjustmentS   <- adjustmentNew (fromIntegral s) 1 1000 1 0 0
   adjustmentE   <- adjustmentNew (fromIntegral e) 1 1000 1 0 0
   seasonButton  <- spinButtonNew adjustmentS 1.0 0
   episodeButton <- spinButtonNew adjustmentE 1.0 0
   removeButton  <- buttonNewWithLabel "remove"
   let getSeries = do
            s <- spinButtonGetValue seasonButton
            e <- spinButtonGetValue episodeButton
            return $ Series name (round s) (round e)
       handleSeries onEvent widget handler = do
            onEvent widget $ do
                series <- getSeries
                handler series

    handleSeries onValueSpinned seasonButton  changeHandler
    handleSeries onValueSpinned episodeButton changeHandler
    onPressed removeButton $ do
        series <- getSeries
        containerRemove table nameLabel
        containerRemove table seasonButton 
        containerRemove table episodeButton 
        containerRemove table removeButton 
        removeHandler series

    let tadd widget x = tableAdd table widget x (rows - 1)
    tadd nameLabel     0
    tadd seasonButton  1
    tadd episodeButton 2
    tadd removeButton  3
    widgetShowAll table


main :: IO ()
main = do

    initGUI

    window     <- windowNew
    scroll     <- scrolledWindowNew Nothing Nothing
    table      <- tableNew 1 5 True
    addButton  <- buttonNewWithLabel "add series"
    vbox       <- vBoxNew False 10

    containerAdd window vbox
    boxPackStart vbox addButton PackNatural 0

    let networkDescription :: forall t. Frameworks t => Moment t ()
        networkDescription = do

            addEvent <- eventButton addButton

            (changeHandler,fireChange) <- liftIO $ newAddHandler
            changeEvent <- fromAddHandler changeHandler
            (removeHandler,fireRemove) <- liftIO $ newAddHandler
            removeEvent <- fromAddHandler removeHandler

            let insertIntoTable' = insertIntoTable table fireChange fireRemove
                addSeries e = do
                     s <- addSeriesDialog
                     liftIO $ insertIntoTable' s

            liftIO $ mapM_ insertIntoTable' initSeries

            reactimate $ addSeries         <$> addEvent
            reactimate $ updateSeries conn <$> changeEvent
            reactimate $ removeSeries conn <$> removeEvent

    network <- compile networkDescription
    actuate network

    onDestroy window $ do
        D.disconnect conn
        mainQuit

    widgetShowAll window
    mainGUI
```

I want to refactor the insertIntoTable method to use events and behaviors rather than using simple callbacks.

**EDIT:**

I have tried the gtk [TreeView](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/gtk/0.12.4/doc/html/Graphics-UI-Gtk-ModelView-TreeView.html) with a [ListStore](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/gtk/0.12.4/doc/html/Graphics-UI-Gtk-ModelView-ListStore.html) backend. In this scenario you don't need dynamic event switching. I have written the `reactiveList` function below to get a list behavior out of insert, change and remove events. It works ^^

```
reactiveList :: (Frameworks t)
    => ListStore a
    -> Event t (Int,a) -- insert event
    -> Event t (Int,a) -- change event
    -> Event t (Int,a) -- remove event
    -> Moment t (Behavior t [a])
reactiveList store insertE changeE removeE = do

    (listHandler,fireList) <- liftIO $ newAddHandler

    let onChange f (i,a) = do
            f i a
            list <- listStoreToList store
            fireList list

    reactimate $ onChange (listStoreInsert store)         <$> insertE
    reactimate $ onChange (listStoreSetValue store)       <$> changeE
    reactimate $ onChange (const . listStoreRemove store) <$> removeE

    initList <- liftIO $ listStoreToList store
    fromChanges initList listHandler


main :: IO ()
main = do

    initGUI

    window     <- windowNew
    addButton  <- buttonNewWithLabel "add series"
    vbox       <- vBoxNew False 10
    seriesList <- listStoreNew (initSeries :: [Series])
    listView   <- treeViewNewWithModel seriesList

    treeViewSetHeadersVisible listView True

    let newCol title newRenderer f = do
            col <- treeViewColumnNew
            treeViewColumnSetTitle col title
            renderer <- newRenderer
            cellLayoutPackStart col renderer False
            cellLayoutSetAttributes col renderer seriesList f
            treeViewAppendColumn listView col
            return renderer

    newCol "Image"  cellRendererPixbufNew $ \s -> [cellPixbuf :=> newPixbuf s]
    newCol "Name"   cellRendererTextNew   $ \s -> [cellText   :=  name s]
    seasonSpin <- newCol "Season" cellRendererSpinNew   $ \s ->
        [ cellRendererSpinAdjustment :=> adjustmentNew (fromIntegral (season s)) 1 1000 1 0 0
        , cellText := (show $ season s)
        , cellTextEditable := True
        ]
    episodeSpin <- newCol "Episode" cellRendererSpinNew   $ \s ->
        [ cellRendererSpinAdjustment :=> adjustmentNew (fromIntegral (episode s)) 1 1000 1 0 0
        , cellText := (show $ episode s)
        , cellTextEditable := True
        ]

    containerAdd window vbox
    boxPackStart vbox listView PackGrow 0
    boxPackStart vbox addButton PackNatural 0

    let networkDescription :: forall t. Frameworks t => Moment t ()
        networkDescription = do

            (addHandler,fireAdd) <- liftIO $ newAddHandler
            maybeSeriesE <- fromAddHandler addHandler
            (removeHandler,fireRemove) <- liftIO $ newAddHandler
            removeE <- fromAddHandler removeHandler

            -- when the add button was pressed,
            -- open a dialog and return maybe a new series
            askSeriesE <- eventButton addButton
            reactimate $ (const $ fireAdd =<< askSeries) <$> askSeriesE

            -- ommit all nothing series
            let insertE  = filterJust maybeSeriesE
                insert0E = ((,) 0) <$> insertE

            seasonSpinE  <- eventSpin seasonSpin  seriesList
            episodeSpinE <- eventSpin episodeSpin seriesList
            let changeSeason  (i,d,s) = (i,s {season = round d})
                changeEpisode (i,d,s) = (i,s {episode = round d})
            let changeE = (changeSeason <$> seasonSpinE) `union` (changeEpisode <$> episodeSpinE)

            listB <- reactiveList seriesList insert0E changeE removeE
            listE <- (changes listB)

            reactimate $ (putStrLn . unlines . map show) <$> listE
            reactimate $ insertSeries conn       <$> insertE
            reactimate $ updateSeries conn . snd <$> changeE
            reactimate $ removeSeries conn . snd <$> removeE

            return ()

    network <- compile networkDescription
    actuate network

    onDestroy window $ do
        D.disconnect conn
        mainQuit

    widgetShowAll window
    mainGUI
```

I'm open for comments and suggestions.

Comment: It would help if we had some code to work from, as well. In particular, what is your underlying data structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your problem is much closer to the [Bar Tab](https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/reactive-banana/blob/master/reactive-banana-wx/src/BarTab.hs) example than the CRUD one.

The basic idea for adding new widgets--along with new behaviors and events--is to use so-called "dynamic event switching". Essentially, this is a way to put newly created events and behaviors back into your network.

The action to create a new widget has two parts. The first part is to just create the widget, using `liftIO`. The second is to get its inputs and use [`trimE`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/reactive-banana/0.7.1.1/doc/html/Reactive-Banana-Switch.html#v%3atrimE) or [`trimB`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/reactive-banana/0.7.1.1/doc/html/Reactive-Banana-Switch.html#v%3atrimB) as appropriate. Leaving out most of the GTk-specific details (I don't know how to use GTk :P), it'll look something like this:

```
let newSeries name = do 
  label <- liftIO . labelNew $ Just name
  liftIO $ tadd labelNew 0
  {- ... the rest of your controls here ... -}
  seasonNumber <- trimB $ getSpinButtonBehavior seasonButton
  {- ... wrap the rest of the inputs using trimB and trimE ... -}
  return (label, seasonNumber, ...)
```

So this function creates a new widget, "trims" its inputs and returns the values to you. Now you have to actually use these values:

```
newSeasons <- execute (FrameworkMoment newSeries <$> nameEvents)
```

here `nameEvents` should be an `Event String` containing an event with the name of the new series each time you want to add it.

Now that you have a stream of all of the new seasons, you can combine it all into a single behavior of a *list* of entries using something like `stepper`.

For more details--including things like getting the aggregate information out of all of your widgets--look at the actual example code.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I try that out and post the results, before I accept the answer.